# Using Boost::boost::asio::ip::udp from a model plugin

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi everyone,

I'm trying top use a custom UDP socket to control a model. The outgoing (from Plugin) messages are received but the plugins doesn't receive anything from the source. The messages are being queued. It's not the port because I tried to use the code outside gazebo and it works.

Any idea why, and how to fix this?

Thx!

XB32Z

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13940/using-boost::boost::asio::ip::udp-from-a-model-plugin/) by [XB32Z](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2505/xb32z/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 23 on 2016-07-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The solution is to move the receiver to a thread (tested) or use the IO_service of gazebo (access via IOManager) (non-tested)
The porblem is that the same thread cannot access io_services via two different boost::io_services

---

Originally posted by [XB32Z](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2505/xb32z/) with karma: 23 on 2016-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0